# Facebook php ads sdk CurlLogger.php

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

```
Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in /var/www/myapp/vendor/facebook/php-ads-sdk/src/FacebookAds/Logger/CurlLogger.php on line 182
```

I have this error... how fix that ?  and this code is in on that line

```
fwrite($this->handle, $buffer.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL);
```

I tried to debug and return this:

```
curl -G \ -d 'level=account' \ -d 'filtering=[]' \ -d 'breakdowns=["age","gender"]' \ -d 'time_range={"since":"2017-09-06","until":"2017-10-06"}' \ -d 'fields=results,result_rate,reach,frequency,impressions,delivery,social_reach,social_impressions,total_actions,total_unique_actions,relevance_score:score,relevance_score:positive_feedback,relevance_score:negative_feedback,spend,today_spend,cost_per_result,cpp,cpm,cost_per_total_action,actions:page_engagement,actions:like,actions:mention,actions:tab_view,actions:comment,actions:post_engagement,actions:post_reaction,actions:post,actions:photo_view,actions:rsvp,actions:receive_offer,actions:checkin,cost_per_action_type:page_engagement,cost_per_action_type:like,cost_per_action_type:mention,cost_per_action_type:tab_view,cost_per_action_type:comment,cost_per_action_type:post_engagement,cost_per_action_type:post_reaction,cost_per_action_type:post,cost_per_action_type:photo_view,cost_per_action_type:rsvp,cost_per_action_type:receive_offer,cost_per_action_type:checkin,actions:video_view,video_10_sec_watched_actions:video_view,video_30_sec_watched_actions:video_view,video_p25_watched_actions:video_view,video_p50_watched_actions:video_view,video_p75_watched_actions:video_view,video_p95_watched_actions:video_view,video_p100_watched_actions:video_view,video_avg_time_watched_actions:video_view,video_avg_percent_watched_actions:video_view,canvas_avg_view_time,canvas_avg_view_percent,canvas_component_avg_pct_view:canvas_view,cost_per_action_type:video_view,cost_per_10_sec_video_view:video_view,actions:link_click,unique_actions:link_click,outbound_clicks:outbound_click,website_ctr:link_click,unique_link_clicks_ctr,call_to_action_clicks,clicks,unique_clicks,ctr,unique_ctr,social_clicks,unique_social_clicks,cost_per_action_type:link_click,cost_per_unique_action_type:link_click,cpc,cost_per_unique_click,estimated_ad_recallers,estimated_ad_recall_rate,cost_per_estimated_ad_recallers' \ -d 'access_token=aaaaaaaaa' \ -d 'appsecret_proof=aaaaaa' \ https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/act_aaaaaaa/insights
```

Code of my file:

```
   <?php


require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use FacebookAds\Object\AdAccount;
use FacebookAds\Object\AdsInsights;
use FacebookAds\Api;
use FacebookAds\Logger\CurlLogger;

$access_token = 'hidden';
$ad_account_id = 'hidden';
$app_secret = 'hidden';

$api = Api::init($app_id, $app_secret, $access_token);
$api->setLogger(new CurlLogger());

$fields = array(
  'actions:link_click',
  'unique_actions:link_click',
  'clicks',
);
$params = array(
  'level' => 'account',
  'filtering' => array(),
  'breakdowns' => array('age','gender'),
  'time_range' => array('since' => '2017-09-06','until' => '2017-10-06'),
);
echo json_encode((new AdAccount($ad_account_id))->getInsights($fields,$params)->getResponse()->getContent(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

This code is generated by facebook  marketing api 
Screenshot here https://prnt.sc/gtqbf5 and use php php 5.6.3

Comment: can you post the code you used to instantiate the api, as the info enough is not enough to debut what's happening.

Comment: I fixed, was issue from my php not have rights to write file...